# What are the tables affected when we submit an order in websphere commerce?

Tags: solr, websphere, commerce, wcs

Orderflow consists of ordercapture, orderprepare, orderprocess, fulfillorder, scheduleorder what are the commands used in each flow step and what are the tables affected in each step?

Answer (score 1):

ORDERS, XORDERS, ORDERITEMS, XORDERITEMS, ORDADJUST, ORDIADJUST

[image: Order Subsystem Data Model]

Answer (score 0):

Fastest way is just to put in a break point in WebSphere Commerce Developer or put in the SQL monitoring in DB2.   Another way if you're really, really lazy is to ask IBM Software Support.